# Can selection be made stable?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Hi I am working on the code stable selection sort,and I have been able to get the correct result, but I am not sure if there are  corner cases in the code.The data I am sorting like this
a[0]=new Data(1,'d');
        a[1]=new Data(2,'c');
        a[2]=new Data(3,'a');
        a[3]=new Data(4,'b');
        a[4]=new Data(5,'d');
        a[5]=new Data(6,'c');
        a[6]=new Data(8,'a');
        a[7]=new Data(9,'a');
        a[8]=new Data(10,'a');

as you can see it is sorted by numbers and I am supposed to sort it by characters now.

So the logic of sort of Data objects I have used is  like this:

in the loop of finding the smallest element, we will not just find the smallest element but smallest element with smallest int. That way order of the elements will remain the same

even though it is working just fine, are there any corner cases I have missed here?

for ex : lets take up itunes, first we sort by the ids of the songs and after that we want to sort by their names. I hope it makes every thing  clear

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I cant tell what you are asking. Also: skipping a[9] and duplicating a[0] just a typo? - you need to get these things accurate when trying to get help in code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have not missed anything. This is the standard technique to make any unstable algorithms stable: impose a total ordering! Any ties are resolved by the second key - which is the input order. I assume you correctly implemented lexicographical ordering here, it's not entirely clear from your description.

Comment: I think we disagree because we have interpreted the input data in two different ways. If the numbers are entirely internal to the sorting program - produced by it and never seen by the outside world - then I agree with you that it is a stable sort. If the program receives the numbers as part of the input data, and is taking advantage of the fact that they happen to be in ascending order, then I think it is not a stable sort.

Comment: Doesn't matter how the numbers are generated. I figured OP generated them manually - but as long as they are sorted, the output will be stable. The whole question is kind of nonsensical anyways from a practical point of view. OP could just use insertion sort or merge sort for stable sorting..

Comment: I know about merge sort. the point is stable sort as such is non-stable so I was trying to implement as stable sort ans problem I had in mind was the problem of itunes.

Comment: Yea, I guess that is an interesting exercise. This technique is more often used with "sorting" data-structures such as trees or priority queues where inherently stable alternatives are more tricky (depending on the context). For sorting alone, you would typically pick insertion sort instead of selection, since it is stable and as easy to implemented. Merge sort is not a whole lot harder, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a sort on a composite key: the most significant part of the key is the character, and the least significant part of the key is the number.

This is not what I would call a stable sort. With a stable sort, where two records have the same value of the key, the first one in the sorted sequence is the first one in the original data, but in your case the first one is the one with the lowest number.

With a stable sort, if you gave it data in which the numbers were in descending order, then if two records had the same letter, the first record of the two in the sorted data would be the record with the largest number, because this is the first record in the input data. With your program, the first record of the two would be the record with the smallest number.

Comment: If the numbers were initially sorted (and the question says they are), then the sort would be stable.

Comment: See my comment to your answer. In real life I guess I would appeal to a specification to see what the program can assume about its input data. Based on the little we know here, since you can get a stable sort without relying on special features of the input data, I think a program that only produces a stable sort when the input data obey a particular restriction is not really a program for stably sorting data.